# Workflow for working with local typescript packages

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

So `npm link` is something that comes up a lot, but I haven't seen a successful implementation to date.

My wish is for the following workflow:

- I have an application that uses two packages on NPM which somebody developped
- I would like to contribute to this package and see if I can add functionality I like
- I'm used to editing packages live, and seeing the result in my own program

The final part seems impossible with angular/typescript, are there are ways of making `npm link` work with types and instant results?

Because afaik  symlinks do not work, the only thing that **might** work is doing:
*  Compiling in the packages
* `npm i --save PATH_TO_TARBALL` 
* repeat on every change to files

Which would seem tedious at best. Am i missing some grand document which shows me how to do this, or does everybody just solely use tests to make new features?

Comment: What went wrong when you tried `npm link`?  FWIW, I recommend the use of relative-path "versions" in `package.json` over `npm link` because it can be done per-project and `npm link` is system-wide, but the approaches have very similar properties.  Getting types is a matter of generating declaration files and setting the `types` field in `package.json` correctly.

Comment: Absolutely everything, my vs code would not load the package (so no type hinting) and it wouldnt compile because it couldnt find the modules.

I did the relative path version, but then you have to `npm i`the package specific packages.

I dont want the types per se, I want to debug all of it :) The relative-path thing helped though, yeah.

Comment: If you generate source maps for the package, then when you debug it, your debugger should show the TypeScript source.  Likewise, if you generate declaration maps, then the "Go to definition" command on a reference to an element defined in the package should jump to the `.ts`, not the `.d.ts`.  If there's a specific feature you want and still can't get to work using the relative-path approach, let me know.

Comment: Well the relative-path thing works, VS code works. But I am developping an application, and want the package to be included when I want it, but when I commit it should use the latest one on npm. I sort of want to side-load the extra package when I can. Is this something not currently supported?

In either case, I do not want to have to install the packages of the `relative-path`'d package, which i currently have to...